# dmcryt_write process in TOP but no WRDSK indicated

Tags: luks

I am using LUKS over RAID0. I have executed `cryptsetup -v --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512  --hash sha256 --iter-time 2000 --use-urandom --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/md0`

Everything shows me that the partition is LUKS protected `/dev/mapper/raid0luks` is active

When I am writing on this partition, it is fast, so I wanted to monitor the overall process. TOP shows me the `dmcrypt_write` process 20% CPU usage, whereas iotop shows 0 bytes written on dmcrypt_write line.

I would like to be sure I am not missing something due to good write performances.
Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. I haven't looked into it too deeply, but I would assume that `dmcrypt_write` is writing at a lower level than where the statistics happen.

Good performance should be expected on any CPU supporting the AES-NI instruction set, `dmcrypt_write` never goes higher than 2% CPU usage for me when writing around 185 MiB/s. Performance testing with `openssl` gives me around 1.8 GiB/s for AES-256 in CTR mode.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to investigate more and post update on that topic. I can clearly see CPU usage on dmcrypt with tool like atop : 20% every 1s. Moreover, it indicates write ope on LVM which in my case is associated to  /dev/mapper, write ope on RAID0 (layer under), write ope with ftpd (client write ope) BUT dmcrypt_write is 20% CPU and no write ope